# How to plot weighted means by group?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am looking for a straightforward way to plot weighted means by group on a line chart (each line representing a country, example provided below).

My data has a hierarchical structure where individuals nested in countries and countries nested in years, but not all countries have surveys in each year. Here is my attempt to create a minimal data frame similar to my data:

```
dat <- data.frame(country=rep(LETTERS, each=3)[1:20], replicate(3, sample(11, 10)), year=sample(c(1990:2000), 100, TRUE),wght=sample(c(1:3), 100, TRUE))
```

I managed to calculate weighted.means by country-year with the following code and I saved it as a matrix:

```
mat1<-by(dat,list(dat$country,dat$year), function(x)with(x,weighted.mean(x$X1,x$wght)))[]
```

But this is how far I could get. Can somebody please help me with plotting the weighted averages by country-year from this matrix or offer an  alternative way to plot weighted averages by groups?

To be perfectly clear, this is how I need my graph to look like:

[image: Weighted average by country]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

1. `plyr` or `data.table` to aggregate your data
2. `lattice` or `ggplot2` to plot by group

For example using `plyr`/`lattice`:

```
library(plyr)
mat.mean <- ddply(dat,.(country,year),summarise, value=weighted.mean(X1,wght))
library(lattice)
xyplot(value~year,groups=country,
       type='l',data=mat.mean,
       auto.key =list(columns = 3))
```

[image]